# Covered call help

Tags: stocks, call-options, covered-call-writing

I sold a covered call and received the premium right away.
Question is the call now is the money and my total return shows negative. If when this call gets called away or close by expiration date does that minus return get subtracted from my call premium or my account money?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

When you sell a covered call, you receive a cash credit in the amount of the premium times 100 less any commissions paid and/or fees.  Your account will show a short call with a debit balance equal to the current price of the call.

While the short call is open, its debit balance will fluctuate, rising if the call's price increases and dropping if the call's price decreases.

If you buy to close the call before expiration, you'll pay the then current price and the debit balance will disappear.  It will also disappear if the short call expires or is exercised.

Answer (score 0):

> If when this call gets called away or close by expiration date does
> that minus return get subtracted from my call premium or my account
> money?

If called away, the negative return that you are seeing will disappear. There will be a profit/loss in the shares that are called away, but this is not aggregated in your app to show the overall profit/loss of your covered call.

If closed by expiration, the negative return that you are seeing will disappear. You will be left with the call premium and will still have the shares that were covering a potential call.